# SOAP Implementation in Forms Project

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL from the Shipping Service Hermes and want to use it with C#. I added the WSDL to my Project and can use the Functions within it.

([This](https://hermesapi.hlg.de/hermes-api-props-web/services/v15/ProPS?wsdl) is the WSDL link.)

I allready tried something like this but with no success:

```
HermesWeb.ProPS Prop;
HermesWeb.HermesLogin HermesLogin = new HermesWeb.HermesLogin();
HermesLogin.benutzername = "***";
HermesLogin.kennwort = "***";
HermesWeb.propsUserLogin Login = new HermesWeb.propsUserLogin(HermesLogin);
Prop = new HermesWeb.ProPSClient();
Prop.propsUserLogin(Login);
```

Am I doing it completely wrong? I must say I'm a newbie at WSDL. When I Google it I get tutorials with XML and so on. Do I need XML? Doesn't adding it to my project already convert the XML to C# functions and variables?

The Error I get is:

> Fault occurred while processing. Fault.Exception´1

Comment: The error sounds like its happening on the service side.  Have you talked to the support people at Hermes?   They should be your first stop.

Comment: How did you "add the WSDL to you project"?

Comment: I added the WSDL As Service and put in the URL.

Comment: I believe you mean "Service Reference"?

Comment: Please see https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: Yes I mean Service Reference. I did exactly like this. I tried the code above and slightly other code but still gives me that error. I'm a little stuck in here. I got an implemantation Guide for it but it just contains something for the wsdl

Comment: Can't someone help me please??